# Async web scraping in Rust

Tags: asynchronous, web-scraping, rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to perform asynchronous and parallel HTML scraping in Rust using **tokio**, **reqwest** and **scraper** crates. I have a loop that iterates through HTML elements and uses tokio::spawn to process each element concurrently. However, I encountered an issue with the ElementRef type not implementing the Send trait, preventing its use in an asynchronous context.

Example:

```
<div class="aside">....</div>
<div class="aside">....</div>
<div class="aside">....</div>
```

Code:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Res<()> {
    ...
    let response = reqwest::get(url).await?;
    ...
    let document: ElementRef<'_> = document.root_element();

    for node in document.select(&ASIDE_SELECTOR) {
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            // Parse, insert to Db, etc.
            // Issue: ElementRef is not Send, preventing async usage
            println!("{}", node.inner_html());
        });
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

How can I resolve this issue and perform asynchronous and parallel HTML scraping in Rust? Are there alternative types or approaches that can be used in this context?

Comment: As `ElementRef` is `!Send`, it can't leave the current thread. You can use `tokio::spawn_local()` instead of `spawn()`, which guarantees that the Future passed to it will only execute on the current thread, lifting the `Send`-requirement. This may be detrimental to the parallelism you expect, though.

Comment: Alternatively collect whatever info you need out of the element and then use that in the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fails because `ElementRef` contains a reference to the document structure, but independent Tokio tasks have no lifetime restrictions, therefore the future passed to `tokio::spawn` is required to be `'static`.  This contradiction causes the error.

Note also that any spawned background tasks will be terminated when the main task (`main()` in this case) terminates, so this code would kick off a bunch of background tasks and then terminate them likely before they can do any work at all.

It's unlikely you actually need to spawn a task for each element.  Consider instead converting the `select` iterator to a [stream](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html).  Once you have done so, you can map each element to a future and await them all concurrently using [the `buffer_unordered` combinator](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.buffer_unordered).  This will solve both problems.

Something like this:

```
futures::stream::iter(document.select(&ASIDE_SELECTOR))
    .map(|node| async move {
        // Parse, insert to db, etc.
    })
    // Run up to 16 concurrently.
    .buffer_unordered(16)
    .await;
```

If you do not need to collect any results from the task futures, you could use [the `for_each_concurrent` combinator](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.for_each_concurrent) instead of `map` and `buffer_unordered`.

Note that these futures will not be able to run in parallel on multiple CPUs/cores.  If you are mostly waiting on e.g. database insertion and other I/O, this is probably fine.  If you have to do a significant amount of CPU-bound work, you may need to offload that to another thread using `spawn_blocking` and then you are probably back to square one regarding the lifetime issue.  In that case, you may need to take a different approach, such as scoped threads, shared ownership via `Arc`, or pre-processing the `ElementRef` into a set of owned data (that is, doing the parsing and data extraction outside of the future created in `map` and moving it into the future).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! It indeed helped to execute the code concurrently. However, I am disappointed because it did not provide any performance improvement compared to synchronous code

Comment: @vsezanatodazheeto We'd need to see the exact code you're running to determine why that might be.